# Filter the middle row of each group

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), 
             x=c(1,2,3,3,5,1,4,3,1,2,8,9,3,1,0))
```

For each group, if I want to filter the first row

```
 df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
filter(row_number()==1)
```

What do I do if I have to filter the most middle row?

Comment: For each id, I want to select the middle row. That's why I am grouping it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`n()/2` halves the `nrow` of the group, `ceiling` rounds up decimals for odd values.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(row_number()==ceiling(n()/2))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     3
3     3     3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `slice` rather than `row_number()` and do use `n()` to capture the length of each group. Divide that by 2 to get the middle value of each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 slice(ceiling(n()/2))
```